# Is it faster to use push_back(x) or using an index (capacity)?

Tags: c++, vector

I learned 2 ways of inserting elements into a `vector`.

And I've been wondering which way is faster since I'm working with time limits.

Method 1:

```cpp
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> v(n);
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
  cin>>v[i];
}
```

Method 2:

```cpp
int n;
cin>>n;
vector<int> v;
for(int i = 0;i<n;i++){
  int x;
  cin>>x;
  v.push_back(x);
}
```

If you have a better method to suggest, it'd be appreciated!

Comment: #2 can be made faster by calling `reserve`

Comment: When in doubt, measure (profile) an optimized release build. But in this case just make sure your vector has enough capacity before adding items to avoid re-allocations. Method 1 does this, Method 2 can be made to do this (as Paul mentions)

Comment: What is the largest value of `n`?  Why is there user input `cin` in your code?  What if the person entering the data is a slow typist?

Comment: @PaulSanders #1 would work the same

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It can go up to 10^9, and there isn't really a person typing, it's a system that does that. I believe (codeforces.com)

Comment: As I editted, there isn't really a person typing these, it's an automated process.

Comment: write code to express intent not to outsmart the compiler. The compiler is much better to optimize code. You do not want an empty vector, you also do not want a vector that has space for an unknown number of elements. You want either a vector with n elements or with space for n elements, so use that.

Comment: I bet the coding challenge doesn't require entering a billion numbers in a vector.  What exactly is this "challenge"?

Comment: Standard answer: measure don't guess. Guesses are often wrong. Guessing: for int, method 1, as for large enough n method 2 would trigger reallocations. For other types, who knows, as method 1 has to construct and later assign objects. In general, @PaulSanders' reserve combined with emplace_back rather than push_back. Minimize allocations and minimize constructions/copy assignments.

Comment: Tactical note:  While testing consider taking the performance hit and using `at` in place of `[]`. It'll quickly let you know if your algorithm wanders out of bounds. Once you are sure that you aren't, switch back to `[]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie There actually is, https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1559/A

Comment: side note: Method 1A: `vector<int> v(n); for(int & val: v){ cin>>val; }` Range-based for loops are very hard to screw up.

Comment: @AbdullahAhmed: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1559/A does not require an 10^9 array. If you're using a 10^9 array, then your solution will be too slow and get a TLE (Time Limit Exceeded) error.  It requires an array of length 100.

Comment: Reading a billion numbers, regardless of which method, is slow.  These competitive programming questions are designed so that naive implementations can be coded up quickly, but never pass due to time limitations.  Your "vector of a billion items" approach tends towards the naive solution.

Comment: @MooingDuck It says that the input array can get up to 10^9 integers, not necessarily requiring that capacity, and the time limit for that is enough to handle. Inputting isn't gonna take a lot of time either.

Comment: @AbdullahAhmed --  What if you got a billion numbers, but the range is [0 - 10]?  Are you going to waste time reading in all of that unnecessary data?  The issue is you are creating a vector of a billion items, and that isn't necessary.

Comment: Questions that have input sizes that are huge are almost always a trap set up by these competition sites.  Either you know the "trick" or you will waste time getting time-out errors.  For example, getting the top or bottom "k" items in a gigantic amount of data -- that is solved by creating a min or max heap of `k` items, not by reading the entire dataset into a container and sorting it (that would be the naive approach).

Comment: @AbdullahAhmed no, it says that the input array can get up to 100 integers.  The *values* of those integers are 0 through 10^9, but there's only 100 integers.

Comment: First, (as usual) @MooingDuck is correct. "The first line of each test case contains a single integer n (1≤n≤100) — the length of the sequence", so it's a maximum of 100 numbers to read. Second, even if it was 1e9 items, the time to `push_back` will be dwarfed by the time to read the data from storage, so even if the number was larger you're mostly looking in the wrong place (though it was 1e9 items, you'd do well to see if you can use something like `mmap`).

Comment: Considering you're using console IO, I am guessing that is going to be the bottleneck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both have issues:
You should be using `reserve(n)`

```
int n;
cin >>  n;
vector<int> v;
v.reserve(n);
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
    int x;
    cin >> x;
    v.emplace_back(x);
}
```

#### In the first version: Setting size.

Here you have the issue that you are constructing all the elements in the array. Now for integers this may be insignificant. But if we extend this to non integer types that have a constructor that needs to be called for each element and then you are using the assignment operator to copy over them.

#### The second option: push_back

Here you run into the risk of the underlying storage being reallocated (potentially multiple times). Each time you re-allocate you need to copy the data from the old storage to the new storage.

Again this hurts for integers but really hurts for types with constructors and destructors.

#### Prefer: emplace_back()

Rather than pushing where you need a fully constructed object. You can use emplace_back and pass in the objects used to construct the object. This allows the vector to construct the object in place. If you have simple integers or classes with effecient move semantics then not an issue but worth it as a general habit.

Comment: **Prefer: reserve + emplace_back()**

Comment: @MooingDuck emplace_back is unlikely to make any difference with int.

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili: `emplace_back` is almost always better, and is ~never worse, and should be recommended and used in all cases, unless careful analysis of a specific case shows otherwise.

Comment: @MooingDuck https://abseil.io/tips/112 suggests: *if both `push_back()` and `emplace_back()` would work with the same arguments, you should prefer `push_back()`, and likewise for `insert()` vs. `emplace()`*.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1 is faster because it avoids the need for reallocation of the underlying array of the vector.

Comment: how much faster is it when `n = 1` ?

Comment: But it does incur the cost of zeroing the entire backing array before reading the correct values into it, a penalty you don't pay with `reserve`.

Answer (score 1):

Between the two methods you mentioned, **Method 1 is generally faster** than Method 2 because it avoids the **overhead of resizing the vector** and moving elements when pushing back new elements. In Method 1, the vector is initialized with the required size upfront, so there is no need for reallocation or element shifting.

For small or moderate-sized vectors, the performance difference may not be significant enough to be a concern (When you deal with a greater scale, than you'll actually observe a difference in performance).

If you're working with a time limit and need to optimize the performance further, you can try a hybrid approach that combines the advantages of both methods. Here's an example:

```
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(n); // Reserve memory for n elements
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int x;
      cin >> x;
      v.push_back(x);

}
```

In this approach, you use v.reserve(n) to `preallocate` memory for n elements in the vector, which can help avoid frequent reallocations during the push_back operations. This can provide some performance improvement over Method 2, especially for larger vectors!

Comment: Worth to mention that if you're adding movable objects to your vector, use the emplace_back method, so your object will be moved instead of constructing it and then moving it. Same amortized constant complexity as the push_back method.

Comment: It can also provide some performance advantages over method 1, but measure it to be sure.